# Laptop iLife ZED Note 14 Slow Processor

Tags: cpu

I have an iLife ZED Note 14. The processor is very slow and running at 50 to 100% most of the time, even thought I do not have any applications installed. Also it pairs with AirTurn Duo500 (page turner), then connects and disconnects, and so on. Please advise. Thanks & Regards.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The Intel Atom Z3735F in the [iLife Zed Note 14](https://gds.jo/ilife-zed-note-14) is not a particularly fast processor at the best of times. In fact I'd go so far to say that it's performance is going to be rather poor at best. That you only see it 50% used just means you are not doing anything which needs more than 1-2 cores and your processor has 4 cores. It is normal for some programs to not use many processors.

Comment: Also with only 2GB of RAM Windows 10 is going to be paging out memory quite a lot and will hinder performance that way. I really would not expect much from that machine at all.

Comment: What is your specific question? To make it faster? As suggested, increasing RAM is cheap and might help somewhat... or not. To fix connection issue? If used for music, play *larghissimo*?

Comment: My question is basically that my iLife cannot hold (stay connected) with my AirTurn Duo500 (page turner) via Bluetooth, it keeps cutting out. What to do to keep my AirTurn connected to my iLife ? Thanks.